# DWORD_PTR to DWORD conversion warning

Tags: c++, compilation, compiler-warnings

I have a 64 bit application which had one of the typecast like this:

```
void fun(DWORD_PTR p)
{
}
int* p = (int*)0x1000000010000000;
fun((DWORD)p);
```

I expected compiler to throw a warning for the `fun((DWORD)p);` call saying possible loss of data due to narrowing conversion. Even with 'EnableAllWarnings' setting in Visual Studio 2013 I do not get any warning. Is there any automated way to detect such issues?

Comment: `fun((DWORD)p);` - this is real error. must be `fun((DWORD_PTR)p);`

Comment: Using C-style casting is telling the compiler "I know what I'm doing, don't interfere". If that cast is wrong, then that will of course lead to problems (undefined behavior). That's why one should never use C-style casting in C++ programs.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Even if I use reinterpret_cast<DWORD> I dont get warning. Is that also expected?

Comment: VS2015 complains `warning C4302: 'type cast': truncation from 'int *' to 'DWORD'`. Also there is an `/RTCc` compilation flag to enable runtime detection of data loss during conversion to smaller type. Have you considered upgrading (probably it is worth to jump to VS2017 at this point)?